# Why is this declaration of a custom class not acceptable?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

In my code I want to declare an instance of my custom class like this:

```
 MyClass anInstance;
 if(something){
      anInstance = MyClass("instantiated like this");
 }else{
      anInstance = MyClass("not instantiated like that");
 }
 //use my anInstance object
 ...
```

My IDE is flagging the first line where I declare `anInstance`, it says: `No matching constructor for initialization of 'MyClass'`

Is there something illegal about this?

Comment: @Marcelo I edited the question to answer you.

Comment: when you do MyClass anInstance; , you are creating the object by calling the Class constructor with no arguments. If you had not written such a MyClass() constructor taking no arguments, you get this error as it is looking for exactly such a thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MyClass` probably lacks a default constructor. If so, you need to initialize it when you declare it. Something like this:

```
MyClass anInstance(something ? "instantiated like this" : "not instantiated like that");
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, neat. It seems like it makes the code a little less readable though. Maybe as my c++ eyes develop i'll change my mind.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of situation that the ternary conditional is made for -- better embrace it while you can! :-)

Comment: Addition of default constructor worked for the old code, Ill try using this fancy new inline syntax though. Thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

The forward declaration is not sufficient to do anything else that what would result in a pointer.

If you need to do anything like instantiating the class you will need the full declaration.  Is there any reasons why you are not just pulling in the .h files that contain the class?

Comment: Who's talking about forward declarations? `anInstance` is a variable, not a type.

Comment: I am `#include` ing the appropriate header file

Answer (score 1):

Provide a constructor for MyClass that takes a string literal like this:

```
MyClass {
   public:
   MyClass(const std::string &s):str(s) {}
};
```

Comment: In my actual code, it gets fed a c++ string, I just simplified it for the question, Im confident there is no type mismatch there.

Comment: Implicit conversions are confusing and usually unnecessary. Why would you recommend putting one in a class that you otherwise know nothing about?

Comment: In real code yes, I've only provided this example as a guess, maybe just to explain the cause of error.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    MyClass() {}
    //other code
};
```